# RegEx in C# for space or (

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I have a string which will have a space and ( or just (. 
I need to split the string into 2 based on either the space for (.

Below are sample Strings

```
1234(207) 
1234 (207)
1234 207
```

The result for all the above scenarios should be.

```
string1=1234
string2=(207)
```

I have a code in c#

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(^.*?)\s+(.*?$)"); 
Match m = r.Match(strAbove);
firstPart = m.Groups[1].Value;
secondPart=m.Groups[2].Value;
```

What will be the RegEx pattern for the above mentioned scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1):

Without an actual test, it looks like you have a few minor issues:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^(\d+)\s*(\(\d+\))$");
```

First off, the ^ and $ need to go outside the capturing parenthesis. The whitespace should be a * instead of +, because it is 0 or more, not 1 or more. Last, the literal parenthesis should be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an example that doesn't include the parentheses but you want them in the output you either have to add them afterwards or reformat your input string accordingly. I'd do the former which is a bit easier.

```
var match = Regex.Match(s, @"^(\d+)[ (]+(\d+)";
var string1 = match.Groups[1].Value;
var string2 = "(" + match.Groups[2].Value + ")";
```

Comment: You forgot to escape the parenthesis in the `[ \(]`

Comment: No, I didn't. Why would it need escaping?